# What is wrong with my python syntax for my text based game?

Tags: python

```
print "You wake up in a dark room, There is a box of matches in your pocket. What do you do?"
print "#1 Light a match #2 Do nothing"
door = raw_input(">")
if door == "1":
    print "You light a match, In the room there is an axe and a door without a handle. What do you do?"
    print "#1 Grab the axe #2 Punch the door #3 Do nothing"
    axe = raw_input(">")
    if axe == "1":
        print "You grab the axe, What do you do?"
        print "#1 Knock down the door #2 Do nothing"
        end = raw_input(">")
        if end == "1":
            print "You are free! You Win!"
        elif end == "2":
            print"You wait and then the axe slips out of your hand, decapacitating you. You die"
        else:
            print "Ivalid input. Game End"
            raise SystemExit
    elif axe == "2":
        print"Ow, that hurt. What to do now?"
        print "#1 Grab the axe #2 do nothing"
        chop = raw_input(">")
        if chop  == "1":
            print" You grab the axe, What do you do?"
            print "#1 Knock down the door #2 Do nothing"
            end = raw_input(">")
            if end == "1":
                print "You are free! You Win!"
            elif end == "2":
                print"You wait and then the axe slips out of your hand, decapacitating you. You die"
                raise SystemExit
            else:
            print "Ivalid input. Game End"
            raise SystemExit
        elif chop == "2":
            print "You go insane from waiting. Game Over"
            raise SystemExit
        else:
            print "Ivalid input. Game End"
            raise SystemExit    
    elif axe == "3":
        print "You go insane from waiting. Game Over"
        raise SystemExit
    else:
        print "Ivalid input. Game End"
        raise SystemExit    
elif:
    print"Something in the darkness kills you. Game Over"
    raise SystemExit
else:
    print "Ivalid input. Game End"
    raise SystemExit
```

On executing this code, I get an Error `Unexpected indent`

Comment: Please paste the traceback of the error

Comment: You tell us. What is the problem you're having?

Comment: What ever happened to the "did not bother giving enough information" close option? EDIT: Oh, still there. Awesome.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams "This question appears to be off-topic because it **lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem.** Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself."

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams And then there's [*this*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216491/what-happened-to-the-youre-just-lazy-close-vote-reason).

Comment: I've edited my answer to address the indent error. If you're getting further errors, you'll need to post as a new question. Make sure to read up on how to post a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) question. Primarily, include all lines of the error traceback

Answer (score 3):

The error is in how you're defining variables. You're doing it all over the place, but here's an example:

```
def door = raw_input(">")
```

In Python, `def` is only used for defining *functions*. `door`, being a string, doesn't need anything in front of it

```
door = raw_input(">")
```

---

Additionally, you're mixing tabs and spaces. You need to pick one and stick with it. This is critical. All style guides say use four spaces for your indents. Specifically, you're using tabs on every line except **25, 26, 27, 29, 32,** and **39**

---

This is your first post, so I'd like to help you, but you need to include the **full traceback** when you get errors. They give crucially valuable information, like what line the error was on, and in more complicated code, how the execution reached that line.

---

If you are receiving further errors, you'll need to post them in a *new* question.

Welcome to Stack Overflow

Comment: apparently you can post an answer you'd already started when the question is closed while you're writing it. the more you know!

Comment: Indeed. The key to answering awful questions is to get an answer in ASAP.